# Finding main_data_begin in a MP3 file

Tags: matlab, mp3, decoder

I want to decode a MP3 file. I manage to find the 32 bits in the header (sync word, ID, Layer, Bitrate, etc).  The problem is I have no idea on how to find the starting (the position) of main_data_begin (side information). I am using MATLAB in this case.

I know it may be a simple question, but I really need your help. Please.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPEG1/2 Layer III uses main_data_begin as a kind of pseudo-VBR over the granule headers & data.  The simplest way to do it is to implement a circular buffer that receives all the physical frame data after the side info and throws-away the unused bytes at the beginning of the buffer (as indicated by main_data_begin) before starting frame decode.

Your best bet is to read an existing decoder's source.  The spec is also really good for this, but main_data_begin is mis-documented in publicly-available versions (as best as I can find).

Comment: Thanks @ioctILR :-) Btw, do you have any books to recommend for MP3 decoder?

Comment: Not really.  I hacked together a decoder from the spec using the Fluendo gstreamer decoder to "sanity-check" my logic.  If you want to see how main_data_begin works in that decoder, try reading BitReservoir.cs in nlayer.codeplex.com (especially the AddBits method).